# Filter packets by ttl Scapy?

Tags: scapy, sniffing

I need to have Scapy filter by ttl (e.g.: `sniff(iface = 'eth0', filter = 'ttl 128')` ) but can't seem to find the right syntax for the command to work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a `ttl` keyword for BPF filters, you can do it like that though:

`sniff(iface = 'eth0', filter = 'ip[8] == 128')`